# Separately storing parts of text files and their reconstruction: symlinks with multiple targets?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, symlink, deduplication

I have two text files whose headers are different, while their contents is the same.

```
$ cat original_file_v1
header 1 beginning
header 1 contents
header 1 end
common contents line 1
common contents line 2
...

$ cat original_file_v2
header 2 beginning
header 2 contents
header 2 end
common contents line 1
common contents line 2
...
```

I would like:

- to store the headers in different files and the common contents just once, in a single file, to save space;
- to be able to recreate `original_file_v1` or `original_file_v2` when desired.

This is a sort of deduplication, but only on some selected files.

Is there a way, on **any** Linux filesystem, including `ext` and `ZFS`, to accomplish this? Or is there any external tool which performs this?

---

Just as a proposal, a solution could be a file which consists in an array of symlinks, an ordered **collection** of target files, so that the array actually lets the user access to **all** those files, in the specified order. But I don't know if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using a file archiver such as `tar` will apply compression, and you can recreate the files *when required*, but not transparently

   ```
    tar czf bothfiles.tgz original_file_v1 original_file_v2
    tar cf - original_file_v1 original_file_v2 | gzip > bothfiles.tgz
   ```

   To recover the first file,

   ```
    tar xzf bothfiles.tgz original_file_v1
   ```
2. [S3QL](http://www.rath.org/s3ql-docs/about.html#features) will apply [compression and deduplication](http://www.rath.org/s3ql-docs/impl_details.html#data-de-duplication) by block. For just a few lines it's unlikely you'll hit the point where the deduplication will kick in, but it can be very effective for mostly-similar files. (Despite its name, you [don't need S3 storage](http://www.rath.org/s3ql-docs/backends.html#local) for it to operate.)

   S3QL can be very effective; I use it for holding long-term archive backups.
3. Perhaps it is possible to split each file into its unique and common parts?

   ```
    nl < <(cat header1 common)          # Number the lines from file1
    cp <(cat header2 common) /tmp/f2    # Copy the composite file2
   ```